# How to create a latest timestamp folder and copies latest artifact to the folder using jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a jenkins job that will import the latest artifact using curl command from nexus to jenkins workspace with the help of "execute shell" in jenkins job. Now, i want to copy the timestamp war file (mrdrest_20170401-190243.war) to mrdrest.war from $workspace to the folder (20170401) inside the target folder in the workspace ($workspace/mrdrest/target/)

is there any way without going to jenkins config, once we start the job, it will copy the latest artifact from nexus to workspace and create a same timestamp (20170401) folder inside the target folder, and underneath it copies the latest war from workspace and change the timestamp war file (mrdrest_20170401-190243.war) to simple war (mrdrest.war)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to give the 20170401 folder location to Urban code deploy plugin in my jenkins so that the latest code deploy to Urban code deploy server that helps to deploy the to Dev/QA machines